# Equivalent of .ShowDetail in google apps script

Tags: vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

Trying to write a Google apps-script to show details from a pivot table in google sheets.

In vba I would loop through the range of values in the pivot table and use *Range(XYZ).ShowDetail = True* to create separate sheets of the underlying data - I can right click each value in a pivot in google sheets and select *Show Details* - I want this done via script.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there doesn't seem to be a equivalent way to create sheets from pivot table  programmatically. Consider creating a [feature request in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905)